# Probability : rules of subtraction

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Question** : Probability it will rain of a given day = 0.2. Calculate that probability that it will not rain for 2 days consecutively.

**Solution** : 
$1 - 0.2 = 0.8$ (Prob. it will not rain on a give day)
$0.8 \times 0.8 = 0.64$ (Prob. it will not rain for 2 days consecutive days)

But, Why can't I do it like this :

$0.2 \times 0.2 = 0.04$ (Prob. it will rain on 2 consecutive days)
$1-(0.04)=0.96$ (Prob. it will **not** rain on 2 consecutive days):->Doubt

Comment: The first solution gives the probability that it won't rain on either day. The second solution gives the probability that it won't rain on *both* days. To be frank, the question is ambiguous as currently worded. Either solution could be correct for some reasonable interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

R - rain, NR - not rain

0.64 gives you NR,NR

0.96 gives you NR,NR or R,NR or NR,R

For your problem the correct answer is 0.96, since 0.64 doesn't give you the probability that it will not rain for 2 days consecutive, it gives you the probability that there will be no rain at all.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: You're welcome!